# Using Postgresql, count consecutive numbers in a table, which has length of more than 5

Tags: postgresql

```
Telephone_number
111111111
1111143452
000000000
888888888
5554038291
1111392012
9999999999
2324666666
```

So from the above, I want to have only those records that have the same digit repeated more than 5 times.

The output count should be 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can a regular expression with a repeated back reference.

```
with test (telephone_number) as
     ( values ('111111111')
            , ('1111143452')
            , ('000000000')
            , ('888888888')
            , ('5554038291')
            , ('1111392012')
            , ('9999999999')
            , ('2324666666')
     )                                     
select telephone_number                                  
  from test                                   
 where telephone_number ~ '(\d)\1{5,}';
```

This does depend on how the columns are defined, as numeric or as text.  If numeric definition then you need to play around in converting to text for using a regular expression. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=69b7d05a6b44bc0f6f282ed986eda212).